# How do I get results from a database table based on results from a different table in cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

For example I have the following tables in my database:

- People
- Groups

And in the **People** table I have the following columns:

- Name
- Birthdate
- Group

In the **Groups** table I have the following columns:

- Name
- Colour

Now I want to fetch results from my database to make a list of all the **People**.
So I would use this:

```
$this->set('people', $this->Person->find("all"));
```

And obviously in my view I would loop through the returned array and display it. Now I also want to find out for each person in the list what Colour and Group name they are (retrieved from the **groups** table).

How would I go about this in CakePHP.

Comment: btw, do you follow cake naming conventions?

Comment: I try to usually. I didn't know that I had to name the **group** column **group_id**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure your model relationships are defined. Second, you might want to consider using "id" fields for your related tables (I assume you did and maybe just did not include them in your original questions table definitions).

And yes, run [debug](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1128/debug)($this->Person->find("all")) as Elwhis noted to see what your array is dumping out.

And if this is a mission critical application, be sure to use [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) instead of recursive to prevent taxing queries to your db.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help. I figured it out. I had to make the Group hasMany() Person. Also I named the column group in People to group_id in order to follow the convention.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the `recursive` attribute. But I guess it should work with the default value. Put this line in your controller `debug($this->Person->find("all"))` and check whether the data doesn't already contain you desired group information.

If not, try setting `$this->Person->recursive = 1;` before calling the `find()` function

For more information about `recursive`: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive